# C program to mimic airline seat reservation and boarding isn't properly displaying data

Tags: c, arrays

I have to write this program in C that mimics reserving seats for an airline. The program also has to be able to display a seating chart, manifest, and boarding pass details for any selected seat but whenever I run the program it doesn't seem to be saving the passenger information cause the manifest and boarding pass functions aren't displaying anything. I have tried fiddling with the arrays but I can't figure out what the issue is. Not necessarily asking for a solution but rather guidance.

For seat reservation, the plane has 72 seats, 12 rows. Each row has 6 seats, A,B,C,D,E,F. A and F are window seats. First-class is rows 1-2, Business-class is rows 3-5, and Economy is rows 6-12.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int seatmap[12][7];
char name[72][20];

int assignseat(char c);
void displaymap(void);
void displayboardingpass(int sno);
void displaypassengers(void);

int main()
{
    while(1>0)
    {
        int assignseat(char c);
        void displaymap(void);
        void displayboardingpass(int sno);
        void displaypassengers(void);
        int seatno,i,j, t;
        char temp[20],c;
        for(i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<7;j++)
            {
                seatmap[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        printf("\nWelcome to the AIRLINE RESERVATION SYSTEM\n\n");
        printf("\nPlease Enter your Name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", temp);

        printf("\nPlease type ‘F’ for \"first class\"");
        printf("\nPlease type ‘B’ for \"business class\"");
        printf("\nPlease type ‘E’ for \"economy class\"");
        do
        {
            printf("\n\n\nSelect your seat choice (\'F\' ,\'B\' or \'E\'): ");
            scanf(" %c",&c);
            c=toupper(c);
            if((c!='F') && (c!='B') && (c!='E'))
            {
                printf("\nWrong Choice. Please Enter \'F\' ,\'B\' or \'E\'");
            }
        }while((c!='F') && (c!='B') && (c!='E'));

        seatno=assignseat(c);
        strcpy(name[seatno-1],name);
        seatmap[(seatno-1)/6][(seatno-1)%6]=1;

        printf("\nCongratulations! Your Seat has been booked!\n\n");

        printf("\n(1)Print Seat Map Chart");
        printf("\n(2)List Passenger Details");
        printf("\n(3)Print Boarding Pass");
        do
        {
            printf("\n\n\nSelect your seat choice (1-3: ");
            scanf(" %d",&t);
           if((temp<1) && (t>3))
           {
                printf("\nWrong Choice. Please Enter (1-3)");
           }
        }while((t<1) && (t>3));
        switch(t)
        {
            case 1:
                displaymap();
                break;
            case 2:
                displaypassengers();
                break;
            case 3:
                displayboardingpass(seatno);
                break;
        }
    }

}

int assignseat(char c)
{   int seatno, i, wma;
    char p;

    do
    {
        printf("\n\n\n Enter your seat preference (\'W\' ,\'A\' or \'N\'):\n");
        printf("\n \'W\'-Window ,\'A\'-Aisle, \'N\'-No Preference");
        scanf(" %c",&p);
        p=toupper(p);
       if((p!='W') && (p!='A') && (p!='N'))
       {
            printf("\nWrong Choice. Please Enter \'F\' ,\'B\' or \'E\'");
       }
    }while((p!='W') && (p!='A') && (p!='N'));

    switch(c)
    {   case 'F':
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
               seatno=rand()%12 +1;
               wma=(seatno-1)%6;
               if((p=='W') && ((wma==0)||(wma==5)) && (seatmap[(seatno-1)/6][(seatno-1)%6]==0))
               {
                    return(seatno);
               }
               if((p=='A') && ((wma==2)||(wma==3)) && (seatmap[(seatno-1)/6][(seatno-1)%6]==0))
               {
                    return(seatno);
               }
            }
            for(i=1;i<13;i++)
            {
                if(seatmap[(i-1)/6][(i-1)%6]==0)
                {
                    return(i);
                }
            }
            return -1;
            break;
    case 'B':
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
               seatno=(rand()%(30-13+1))+13;
               wma=(seatno-1)%6;
               if((p=='W') && ((wma==0)||(wma==5)) && (seatmap[(seatno-1)/6][(seatno-1)%6]==0))
               {
                    return(seatno);
               }
               if((p=='A') && ((wma==2)||(wma==3)) && (seatmap[(seatno-1)/6][(seatno-1)%6]==0))
               {
                    return(seatno);
               }
            }
            for(i=12;i<30;i++)
            {
                if(seatmap[i/6][i%6]==0)
                {
                    return(i);
                }
            }
            return -1;
            break;
    case 'E':
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
               seatno=(rand()%(72-31+1))+31;
               wma=(seatno-1)%6;
               if((p=='W') && ((wma==0)||(wma==5)) && (seatmap[(seatno-1)/6][(seatno-1)%6]==0))
               {
                    return(seatno);
               }
               if((p=='A') && ((wma==2)||(wma==3)) && (seatmap[(seatno-1)/6][(seatno-1)%6]==0))
               {
                    return(seatno);
               }
            }
            for(i=31;i<73;i++)
            {
                if(seatmap[i/6][i%6]==0)
                {
                    return(i);
                }
            }
            return -1;
            break;
    }
}

void displaymap(void)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\nSeat Map Table");
    printf("\n\tA\tB\tC\tD\t\E\tF\n");
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",i);
        for(j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",seatmap[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

void displaypassengers(void)
{
    int i,j,k=1;
    printf("\nPassenger Details");
    printf("====================");
    printf("Seat No\tPassenger");
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",i);
        for(j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            if(seatmap[i][j]==0)
            {
                printf("Vacant\n");
            }else{
                printf("%s\n", name[k]);
            }
        }
        k++;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

void displayboardingpass(int sno)
{
    printf("\nName: %s",name[sno]);
    printf("\nSeat Number: %d", sno);
    printf("\nClass: ");
    if(sno<13)
    {
        printf("First\n");
    }else if(sno<31){
        printf("Business\n");
    }else{
        printf("Business\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the AIRLINE RESERVATION SYSTEM                                                                                                                                                     


Please Enter your Name: John                                                                                                                                                                  

Please type ‘F’ for "first class"                                                                                                                                                             
Please type ‘B’ for "business class"                                                                                                                                                          
Please type ‘E’ for "economy class"                                                                                                                                                           


Select your seat choice ('F' ,'B' or 'E'): F                                                                                                                                                  



 Enter your seat preference ('W' ,'A' or 'N'):                                                                                                                                                

 'W'-Window ,'A'-Aisle, 'N'-No PreferenceN                                                                                                                                                    

Congratulations! Your Seat has been booked!                                                                                                                                                   


(1)Print Seat Map Chart                                                                                                                                                                       
(2)List Passenger Details                                                                                                                                                                     
(3)Print Boarding Pass                                                                                                                                                                        


Select your seat choice (1-3: 2                                                                                                                                                               

Passenger Details====================Seat No    Passenger0                                                                                                                                    
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        

1       Vacant
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        

2       Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        

3       Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        

4       Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        

5       Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        

6       Vacant
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        

7       Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant                                                                                                                                                                                        
Vacant
```

Comment: Please break it down into a *Minimal* Complete Verifiable Example.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons just added sample output

Comment: that's a lot of code to ask someone to go through.  Now is a good time to learn how to debug a program.